# How to get max object from list of nested objects in java

Tags: java, list

I want to find max product from the list of Products(nested)

```
public class Product {
     private String id;
     private String name;
     private String status;
     private String parentId;
     private AdditionalEntity additionalEntity;

}

public class AdditionalEntity {

    private String storagePlan;
}
```

I want to get the max product based on storage plan and the value of storagePlan can be null, 100hrs, 150hrs, 300hrs, 500hrs. The storage plan can have duplicates like two products having the same hours (1500hrs). In that case, we can return any of the product(having 1500hrs). **AdditionalEntity can also be null**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Optional<Product> max = listOfProducts.stream()
            .filter(product -> product.getAdditionalEntity() != null 
                    && product.getAdditionalEntity().getStoragePlan() != null)
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(product -> 
                    Integer.valueOf(product.getAdditionalEntity().getStoragePlan())));
```

The `filter` filters any Product objects that has a *null* `AdditionalEntity` or *null* `StoragePlan`. We pass a `Comparator` to the `max` method. It compares the storage plan value as integer.

The result is an *Optional* Product that has the highest storage plan.

Comment: works like a charm . just added null check on product and converted the storage plan to int .. removing the extra hrs in the suffix before converting to int

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to select a number from `storagePlane`, because this is a `String`. You can use either separate `int` value or extract it directly from `String`.

```
// e.g. like this; it's just example of product -> int
ToIntFunction<Product> hours = product -> Integer.parseInt(product.getAdditionalEntity().getStoragePlan().substring(0, 4));
```

And then very simple `for` loop:

```
Product maxProduct = null;

for (Product product : products)
    if (maxProduct == null || hours.applyAsInt(maxProduct) < hours.applyAsInt(product))
        maxProduct = product;
```